# OAuth2 authentication for a Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to invoke (OAuth - Client credentials flow and Authorization Code flow) an http cloud function from python code written in my local.

I have created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on the GCP project.

Below code is used to get an access token but this is go to google login page with an error.
Can we some please help to understand how to invoke a cloud function from local python code ? any examples or guidance will be every helpful.

```py
from google_auth_oauthlib import flow
oauthcredential= "client_secret.json" # OAuth 2.0 Client ID JSON
launch_browser = True # when using locally and False when remote
appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(oauthcredential,scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'])

if launch_browser:
    appflow.run_local_server()
else:
    appflow.run_console()

credentials = appflow.credentials
```

Answer (score 2):

To invoke a protected Cloud Function, you need an identity token and not an access token. You can't generate an id token from your own user credential in your code (only with the `gcloud` command line) and you use a service account key file to achieve this (that is not ideal, as [I explain in this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c)).

In your code, set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable that reference the path of your service account key file and then you can use the [`fetch_id_token`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/oauth2/id_token.html#fetch_id_token) function to get an id token

Comment: Thank you for the input. In fact i want to expose this cloud function end point to other applications (outside GCP) as an API and authenticate through OAuth without a Service Account. That's why i was looking for an AccessToken and not used the service account. your thoughts ?

Comment: Is it service to service call? Service outside GCP calls a Cloud Functions?

Comment: Yes, this is service to service (non-human) calls. We have configured the cloud functions to a Google API gateway. Now we need to authenticate these requests without a service account. Can we do some configuration API Gateway side to integrate with Azure AD or any other options (eg:Okta). Could please provide some guidance around this.

Comment: Can the request sender (the external VM) be authenticated with OAuth2 mecanism? With its own IdP and then generated an id_token (JWT)? Something similar to Okta or AWS cognito