# Execute cloud function from cloud data fusion

Tags: http, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to trigger the cloud function (with trigger type - HTTP) from cloud data fusion pipeline using http sink plugin version 1.2.2. However I receive the SSL error
`java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly`

How do I fix this?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, it is currently not possible to execute a Cloud Function from Cloud Data Fusion using the HTTP sink plugin. This is because you need an OIDC token which must be generated dynamically during runtime, as they have an expiration date. This is what is explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210317/oauth2-authentication-for-a-cloud-function). As explaind in the post, this token should then be added to the header of the request. To generate this token, you need to run a `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command, which you cant do using Data Fusion.

The only workaround I see is to Publish a Pub/Sub message at the end of the pipeline to trigger this Cloud Function (however, dont take this as the solution because I would need more context on the precise use-case).